# Skaffold to redeploy services when new image is available

Tags: minikube, skaffold

I have a minikube env where I bring up all my microservices for testing/development. I would like to update my workflow to use skaffold.

I have a custom builder and I don't want to skaffold to build the images (don't want to use skaffold custom builder option), instead I want skaffold to just monitor minikube build registry and redeploy services when a new image is available for it.

Is this possible with minikube? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Skaffold doesn't support this usecase currently.  We would like to understand more about your alternative build process and why it needs to be done outside of Skaffold?

You could run a polling loop in parallel with `skaffold dev`. This polling loop would periodically invoke something like [k8s-digester](https://github.com/google/k8s-digester) to update manifests for that specific image (I'm not sure if k8s-digester supports querying the Docker Daemon).  `skaffold dev` would then pick up that the manifests were changed and apply it to the cluster, which result in a redeploy when the digest changes.  You might need to use a profile to remove your separately-built image from the artifacts list to prevent Skaffold from trying to build it.